# Add Overlay buttons on top of VLC Player in Cordova Ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, libvlc

I am creating an app using Ionic Framework. In my app I am using cordova [VLC Player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-libvlc). Everything is working fine but now I want to put an overlay over VLC Player. When I click on video it opens VLC player in full screen mode and I cannot do anything. I just want to add an overlay over VLC so I can show text or anything on top of the video.

```
window.libVLCPlayer.play(video_link, options, this.onSuccess, this.onFail);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Muzammil, did you get any solution to show html on top of media player. I want to show html controls on top of live streaming.

Comment: @Prasoon nope, I am customizing the VLC native plugin (JAVA) as this is the only way to customize the native plugin.

Comment: I am working on a cordova app and getting live stream from wowza over CDN. In my case, html5 <video> element is able to play the stream so now showing html overlay has got easy.